# #2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query when i am running this query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    contact_list.id,
    contact_list.contact_number,
    call_history.id,
    call_history.user_id,
    call_history.contact_number,
    call_history.call_type,
    call_history.call_duration,
    call_history.call_date,
    call_history.call_time,
    call_history.audio_file,
    employees.username
FROM
    call_history
JOIN contact_list ON contact_list.contact_number = call_history.contact_number
JOIN employees ON employees.id = call_history.user_id
WHERE
    call_history.id IN(
    SELECT
        MAX(call_history.id)
    FROM
        call_history
    WHERE
        1 AND employees.username LIKE '%bha%'
    GROUP BY
        call_history.contact_number
)
ORDER BY
    call_history.id
DESC
```

Comment: this query working fine in localhost but in server it gives a error on php myadmin

Comment: give us more details about differences between server setup/localhost, is it shared hosting? same database size?... on first it looks to me that it is using too much memory because of this LIKE '%bha%' (when starting with %, ignoring indexes)... also why you have 1 AND .... just remove that "1 AND" from query... run DESCRIBE for that query...

Comment: each time does the connection losses at specific time?

Comment: i removed like keyword and use user id for search but still same problem happening

Comment: what are you doing with this query?

Comment: The could be `wait_timeout` is set low need to increase it.
Off topic: The query can be optimized for better performance but need the table schema for the tables as well as what you are going to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

can you try setting the `max_allowed_packet` variable and run the query again?

```
mysql> set global max_allowed_packet=104857600;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

or you can debug the cause using https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-lost-connection.html

Comment: ini_set('global max_allowed_packet',104857600);                                                                    i used it this way but still in problem

Comment: @Ankitmehra will it possible for you to run this command on the server in mysql shell?